# Copying range of second dynamic table

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

I have two tables placed in many sheets. I go through the sheets copying the data from one of the two tables. The range can vary, so it is not something I can statically code the range.

Each table ends in "Total" so that was the string I was attempting to find in the column and setting the last row equal to "Total's" row.

How do I copy the range of my second table (green background). These tables will not be the same range for each sheet.

I have set it up so the 'addSetB' which copies the first table (blue background) by copying the range and ending at "Total". So for 'addSetC' I tried setting it up so it will begin copying after the first total and stop at the second table, grabbing the range of the second table.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Or how should I go about fixing my current code?

<s>I get</s>

> runtime error 91: "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Highlighting the 'startRow' line.

Updated `Sub addSetC()` code. Now throwing:

> Runtime-error: 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

for `ActiveSheet.Range("L" & startRow & ":Q" & lastRow).Copy` after implementing BigBen's suggestion.

Table layout
[image]

```vb
' Copy range of the green background (not working / throwing errors)
Sub addSetC()

Dim lastL As Long
lastL = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Dim FoundRow As Range
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim rng As Range

With ActiveSheet.Range("L2:L" & lastL)
    'Set startRow to first "Total"
    Set rng = .Find(What:="Total", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then startRow = rng.row
    
    'Set lastRow to second "Total"
    Set rng = .Find(What:="Total", _
                            After:=.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
                            
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then lastRow = rng.row

    ActiveSheet.Range("L" & startRow & ":Q" & lastRow).Copy
End With
                        
Sheets("DATA").Activate
Cells(Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The above code is not copying the second table.

Here's what I used to copy the first table (blue background) which is working. How do implement this in my other subroutine to copy the other table?

```vb
' Copy range of blue background (functioning properly)
Sub addSetB()
    
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="Total", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    Range("L3:Q" & lastRow).Copy
    
    Sheets("DATA").Activate
    Cells(Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
          
End Sub
```

Comment: That means the `Find` did not succeed. You should always specify the `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters when using `Find`, and also test if the find succeeded: `Dim rng As Range`, `Set rng = Cells.Find(...)`, `If Not rng Is Nothing Then`, `startRow = rng.Row`.

Comment: @BigBen I've done what you said and added the `Set rng = Cells.find(...)` for both the `startRow` and `lastRow`. However, I'm now being thrown an Runtime-error: 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error" for my line `ActiveSheet.Range("L" & startRow & ":Q" & lastRow).Copy`

Comment: That means that `startRow` or `lastRow` or both are equal to 0. i.e. the `Find` didn't succeed, so you don't actually have a valid `startRow` or `lastRow` or both.

Comment: I'm confused why for `sub addSetB()` it works great. However, switching it around for `addSetC()` I'm not getting valid values?

Comment: Maybe you need to use a different value for `LookIn` and/or `LookAt`.

Comment: Also remove the `Cells` in `lastRow = Cells.Find`. so that `.Find` refers to `With ActiveSheet.Range("L2:L" & lastL)`

Comment: I use the same values for `addSetB()` and it functions properly. Confused why it wouldn't here? I'm pretty sure I have to use `Lookin:=xlValues` and `Lookat:=xlWhole` because I need to find only `Total` as the exact string in the cell.